# Git Permission Errors when unlinking files

Tags: git

I am having a horrid time trying to work with git on my current setup.

When running

> git pull origin develop

I get the following error:

> error: unable to unlink old 'mydirectory/myfile.py

Running:

> git reset --hard origin/master

I get hundreds of errors e.g.

> error: unable to unlink old 'tests/functional/test.ini' (Permission denied)

I am on a MacBook MacOS Sierra, then using Vagrant for ubuntu VMs.

> File: ‘mydirectory/myfile.py’
>
> Size: 10556        Blocks: 24         IO Block: 8192   regular file
>
> Device: 24h/36d    Inode: 2920333     Links: 1
>
> Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ vagrant)   Gid: ( 1101/ vagrant)

Comment: Perhaps a process has a handle open to this file?  Check the output of `lsof`.

Comment: The file itself looks OK, but "permission denied" to remove it would indicate that the permissions on the *directory itself* are wrong. For instance perhaps `mydirectory` is mode `r-xr-xr-x` or owned by someone other than uid 1000.

Comment: The directory is `Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ vagrant)   Gid: ( 1101/ vagrant)
`

Comment: So, as long as git is running as vagrant, it should be able to unlink the file. I've had Issues (mostly just terrible performance) with *shared* files on vagrant, so that I now run Git things in an Ubuntu VM on local filesystems, but I have not encountered this particular one.